# opencv 2.4.6.0 Video Capture won't open files

Tags: opencv, python-2.7

I'm working with python 2.7 on Windows 7 64bit
I have opencv 2.4.6.0 installed and everything works execpt cv2.VideoCapture
I have this simple code:

```
import cv2

vid = cv2.VideoCapture("input.mov")
flag = vid.grab()
print flag
```

flag is always False
I also tried loading .avi files, still doesn't work.
I have K-light codec pack installed and ffmpeg.
any suggestions?
Thanks!